# CCSID in Message broker

Tags: broker

There is Source and Target applications understanding characters in different CCSIDs.

Source application is connected to queue manager of some default CCSID set.And Target application  also connected to Queue manager with different CCSID set.

I need some clarifications on how these messages are passed and retrieved.
1)Source application  places messages in its Q.This message is in unreadable format.Since both have different CCSID,I hope MQPUT will provide CCSID which is overriden by Source QM's default CCSID.-Please correct if wrong

2)WMB receives the message in MRM format.It parses according to the physical and logical structure specified.-Please clarify whether data conversion happens at this stage itself according to the Target application's CCSID? If not,then how would be the message in readable format when it comes out of message broker?.

3)WMB after parsing sets the OutputRoot.properties for CCSID and Encoding according to the target application's CCSID.Please correct if wrong

4)Finally ,as Target application gets the message MQGET with some CCSID ,it overrides the Target QM's CCSID.Please correct if wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this 2 messages are MRM, you dont need to create 2 Msets, you can use the same.

In Mapping node you can change the CCSID just assigning a value , but you need to know what CCSID is (like 819, 1208 etc...).

You can use ESQL to change CSSID too.

Set OutputRoot.Properties.CSSID = 819;

3) WMB will not change CCSID or Enconding according to the target, WMB cant know what target is waiting for.

4) Yes, when you receive a message, WMB will take enconding and CCSID and overrides it. (You can see it at OutputRoot.Properties).

Answer (score 0):

Creating 2 message sets . one having message set of input type and secondhaving message set of output type .

Set output node message domain as per message set defined to it

Set input node message domain as per message set defined to it

Using map node in between input node and output node will be able to map the contents .

Thanks
Aravind